# Wpf:MediaElement pause & play again disables speed ratio

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I have a mediaElement. I change its speedratio according to my will 1x,2x,3x... It works the very first time but when I pause and play again it simply does not work. It starts playing in 1x speed. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: are u finding any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem.

After some experimentation I found setting the `SpeedRatio` back to `1.0` before calling `Play()` again then waiting for the `Position` to change (typically using a timer) and setting `SpeedRatio` back to the old value seems to work.

Comment: I have a same problem !

Comment: Do not use a timer to correct this, it isn't necessary. If you set the Speed ratio to 1 before you pause then back to your desired playback Speed directly after it will work.